# htaccess rule is not working on localhost

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, redirect

Sorry I changed the previous question. I have problem with .htaccess rewrite rule on localhost, I have .htaccess file in http:// localhost/testing/.htaccess.
I want to change url like below

```
http://localhost/testing/site.php?site=test
```

to

```
http://localhost/testing/test
```

And I have code in .htaccess as

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ site.php?site=$1 [L]
```

Which is working correct, but I have also url like

```
http://localhost/testing/pages.php?site=test&pid=2
```

Here pages.php with two parameters as site name and page id. I want rewrite this as

```
http://localhost/testing/test/2
```

For both conditions I have bellow code which is not working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ site.php?site=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ pages.php?site=$1&pid=$2 [L]
```

Please Help

Thanks :)

Comment: are you sure you activated the mod_rewrite in your xampp?

Comment: Yes I trind `RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule home index.php` and it was working ... on testing/home

Comment: Removed $ sign, but still don't work :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution which worked for me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ site.php?site=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ pages.php?site=$1&pid=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is turn on the `mod_rewrite` on your `Apache` server by performing these steps:

1. Assuming you have unpacked the `xampp` folder in the `C:\` directory, navigate to the folder containing the apache configuration files.
   The full path is `C:\xampp\apache\conf\.`
2. In the conf folder, you will find a file named `httpd.conf`. This file holds all the configuration parameters for apache. Open the file  in a text editor.
3. Search for `mod_rewrite.so` and you will come across a line as follows : `#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`
4. Uncomment the line by removing the hash (#) mark.
5. Save  the file and restart Apache web server.

and also if the file is already in the `testing` folder your code should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^site\.html$ site.php?site_id=$1
```

Comment: It is already uncommented, I restarted XAMPP, but problem is same. Thanks for you answer though.

Comment: Didn't work yet, there can be another problem. Maybe I should reinstall XAMPP.

Comment: are you sure the .htaccess file is in the testing folder and that you changed the code to the new one?

Comment: Yes I am sure it in testing folder and it is exactly .htaccess I renamed htaccess.txt through commond prompt.